# How to moq the method of multilevel interfaces inheritance which is injected to another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, repository-pattern, xunit

**My First Interface**

```
public interface IBaseRepository
{ 
 Task<T> FirstOrDefault<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>>[] 
 includeProperties = null) where T : class;
}
```

**My Second Interface**

```
public interface IGenericRepository : IBaseRepository
{
 //Some methodes;
}
```

**My service class and method to which injected above `IGenericRepository`**

```
public class AService
{
 private readonly IGenericRepository _genericRepository;
 public AService(IGenericRepository genericRepository)
 {
  _genericRepository = genericRepository;
 }
 public async Task<decimal> SaveRequest(Guid genericId)
 {
  .
  .
  var requestType = await _genericRepository.FirstOrDefault<RequestType>(x => 
  x.RequestTypeUuid == genericId); //in this line getting error message.
  .
  .
 }
}
```

**My moq setup in test class for above service methode**

```
public class AServiceTests
{
 private readonly Mock<IGenericRepository> mockGenericRepository;
 private readonly MockRepository mockRepository;
 public AServiceTests()
 {
  this.mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
  this.mockGenericRepository = this.mockRepository.Create<IGenericRepository>();
 }
 private AService CreateAService()
 {
  return new AService(this.mockGenericRepository.Object);
 }
}
```

**My test case method**

```
[Fact]
public async Task SaveRequest_SendingValidData_ExpectedNotNull()
{
 // Arrange
 Guid genericId = new Guid("74jdjd83-8383-3hg7-83jj-e69427931176");
 var fakeReturnRequestType = GetFakeReturnRequestType();
 mockGenericRepository.Setup(x => x.FirstOrDefault<RequestType>(f => f.RequestTypeUuid == 
 genericId, null)).ReturnsAsync(fakeReturnRequestType);
 var objAService = this.CreateAService();
 var result = await objAService.SaveRequest(genericId);

 //Assertion
 . 
 .
}
```

**getting the mocking issue :**

> > Message:  Moq.MockException :
> > IBaseRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.RequestTypeUuid ==
> > value(Services.Impls.AService+<>c__DisplayClass10_0).genericId), null)
> > invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the
> > mock must have a corresponding setup. . . AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
> > IGenericRepositoryProxy.FirstOrDefault[T](Expression`1 predicate, Expression`1[] includeProperties) . .
> > --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: Please use `It.IsAny` inside the `Setup` call for the to be mocked methods parameters, like: `Setup(x => x.FirstOrDefault<RequestType>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<RequestType, bool>>>(), ...)`

Comment: Did my proposed solution work for you?

Comment: yes, its worked for me thanks, but before only I was got solution but not answered here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x.FirstOrDefault<RequestType>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<RequestType, bool>>>(), ...)
```

is worked for me.